# How to restore a saved variable in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to restore a saved variable in tensorflow. Seems like it is very very complicated.

I use the alexnet implementation in http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/

in a python file, alexnet.py,  I define the variable

```
conv5W = tf.Variable(net_data["conv5"][0],name='conv5w')
```

then, I finetune the model and I see that some of its values are changed. I save the finetuned model by typing:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess,"modelname.ckpt")
```

after that, I open a new ipython console and run:

```
from alexnet import *
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("modelname.ckpt.meta")
new_saver.restore(sess, "modelname.ckpt")
```

after that, when i try to retrieve the values of the variables with:

```
conv5W.eval(session=sess)
```

it yields:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv5w
     [[Node: conv5w/_98 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_conv5w", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](conv5w)]]
     [[Node: conv5w/_99 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_conv5w", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

on the other hand, if I initialize variable with:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run([init]) ,
```

this time it yields the initial values in `net_data["conv5"][0]`, not the finetuned ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring from the meta graph prepares the graph, not the data. Restoring data requires adding at training time the values you want to restore to collection objects, and reload these collections at restore time. The [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variables/index.html) shows how (in fact, there is another way, see below).

Another way would be to restore the graph (`tf.write_graph` and `tf.import_graph_def`), then restore all variables from a checkpoint. The official tutorials seem to lead more toward this checkpoint approach (see link above). The meta graph is rather aimed for distributed processing, which requires more work and care.

Answer (score 0):

Eric has answered most of your points. 
I faced a similar problem and a simple workaround to it is:

1. Re-load either the entire graph or import its meta graph (former is
   recommended if you are a newbie). You still haven't run the restore
   function
2. Start your session and initialize all variables
3. Restore (using `tf.train.Saver`) the checkpoint

The issue with your case is that when you run `tf.initialize_all_variables()` after restoring, tensorflow resets them to initial values and you loose your fine-tuned weights.